# WMD Output Issue

Tags: python, django, wmd

I have an issue with my google app engine whereby I am using wmd to input text and save text. In preview mode, I can see the wmd formatted correctly as html, but when I switch to output, I just see unformatted wmd.

I have python-wmd installed, but am assuming that there is some sort of issue whereby python-wmd is being bypassed and ignored.

How can I check that python wmd is working, or can I add a javascript to correct the issue and if so, where does this javascript code go?

I am fairly new to this, so any help is appreciated.

Chris

Comment: Why post a new question to ask the same thing? You don't even provide more information about what you have tried or not from the good answers you have there... This behavior pollutes SO unnecessarily.

Comment: Also, SO is not a forum. I really encourage you to look at the FAQ (top left of this page). From the FAQ: "If your question needs clarification, you will see comments in smaller type below your question. If other users ask you for more information in the comments, edit your question using the edit link just below your original question. Providing clarification promptly will help get you the best answers." Posting an answer is actually for answering the question - not providing additional info. It makes it harder to help you... :-)

Answer (score 0):

[`python-wmd`](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=python-wmd) appears to be a "Driver for the Nintendo Wii Remote" and not a [Markdown](http://code.google.com/p/wmd/) [Editor](https://github.com/derobins/wmd#readme).